# TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key. getting error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda

`from keras import models
modelvgg.layers.pop()
modelvgg = models.Model(inputs=modelvgg.inputs, outputs=modelvgg.layers[-1].output)

### show the deep learning model

modelvgg.summary()`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code that we can see the error!

Comment: Can you share the code to define the `modelvgg` and the code generating the error?

Comment: from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16



modelvgg =VGG16(include_top=True,weights=None)
## load the locally saved weights 
modelvgg.load_weights("Data/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
modelvgg.summary()

Comment: please solve it urgent i am stucking in my project. please hurry

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was due to version incompatibility. You can modify code as shown below

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16 
modelvgg =VGG16(include_top=True,weights=None) 
modelvgg.layers.pop()
modelvgg = Model(inputs=modelvgg.inputs, outputs=modelvgg.layers[-1].output)
modelvgg.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 1000)              4097000   
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```